# Errors in the Phonegap-Manifest

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova

I use Phonegap, because I don't really understand JAVA.
But now I have a problem:

When I create a new Android-Project with Phonegap (`Myfolder/Phonegap/lib/android/bin/create ~/Apps/Example com.example.android test`) and I try to start that default-project in Eclipse, Exlipse gives me four Errors in the AndroidManifest.xml
Here is the created AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
       Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
       or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
       distributed with this work for additional information
       regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
       to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
       "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
       with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

         http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

       Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
       software distributed under the License is distributed on an
       "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
       KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
       specific language governing permissions and limitations
       under the License.
-->
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
      package="com.example.android" android:versionName="1.0" android:versionCode="1" android:hardwareAccelerated="true">
    <supports-screens
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true"
        android:resizeable="true"
        android:anyDensity="true"
        />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_VIDEO"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />   
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />   
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" />


    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:debuggable="true">
        <activity android:name="test" android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"
                android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" android:targetSdkVersion="17"/>
</manifest>
```

And these are the Errors:

```
error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'hardwareAccelerated' in package 'android'

error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'xlargeScreens' in package 'android'

error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'hardwareAccelerated' in package 'android'

error: Error: String types not allowed (at 'configChanges' with value 'orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale').
```

Are there any extensions I need to install?

Thanks for every Answer!